# keyboard backlight in Asus Tuf gaming series?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, asus

using fn + up arrow turns on my keyboard backlight but it is just breathing type (those who use asus tuf series knows that there are some types such as static, breathing, strobing etc... ), now I want to use the static type, in windows using fn + left and right arrow would change that. this breathing type as they say, is really annoying at night, someone plz help me with this,
i have tried xset and rogauracore packages but my system can't use these, i think it is for rog series !!
btw i am new to linux, if it is a simple thing and i haven't tried i am sincerely sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you
https://github.com/legacyO7/Aurora.git

If your kernel version is 5.x or lower, you may need to install Faustus kernel module, in order for it to work